# Sort strings based on the numbers I have sorted

Tags: c

```
int siralama(int liste[], int size) {

    int i, j;
    int element;

    for (i = size - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        element = liste[i];
        j = i + 1;

        while (j < size && liste[j] > element) {
            liste[j - 1] = liste[j];
            j++;
        }
        liste[j - 1] = element;
    }
}
```

I'm sorting some numbers with the above function, but these numbers have string equivalents and I want to sort strings.
Example:

```
int arr2[4] = {3,5,4,7}   => {7,5,4,3}  ( I can)

char arr1[4][2] = {{"a"},{"b"},{"c"},{"d"}} => {{"d"},{"b"},{"c"},{"a"}} ( I can't)
```

Comment: You are most likely looking for the [strcmp](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp) function to compare two strings.

Comment: If your strings are really one-char size, and all of them are ASCII chars (7 bits) then you can do it by just using `int siralama(char liste[],...` instead of `int siralama(int liste[],...`

Comment: It is necessary to provide the equality a = 3, b = 5, c = 4, d = 7

Comment: I wrote symbolically, not in one character size

Comment: `a=3, b=5, etc` Then you need a second array storing the equalities, and used for comparisons with given char/number. You compare with an array and move the element of the other array.

Comment: How can I store these equations

Comment: How would you do it without programming, just by paper and pencil?

Comment: I mean, How can I keep a string comparable to a digit  "name" = 10 I don't know how to do this

Answer (score 0):

When you sort the elements in the `int` array, you refer to them through an index. Just use the same indexes to so sort the `char` array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printThem( int n[], char s[] );

int main() {

    int num[4] = {3, 5, 4, 7}, hold;
    char str[] = "abcd";
    
    printThem( num, str );
    
    hold = num[0];
    num[0] = num[3];
    num[3] = hold;
    
    hold = str[0];
    str[0] = str[3];
    str[3] = hold;
    
    printThem( num, str );
    
    return 0;
}

void printThem( int n[], char s[] )
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        
        printf("%d ", n[i]);
    }
    
    printf(" -->  ");
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        
        printf("%c ", s[i]);
    }
    
    puts("\n");
}
```